# Calculating average path length of a varation of Newmann-Watts model!

Tags: graph-theory, network

This problem is from Networks: An Introduction by Newmann.

Consider the following variation on the small-world model. Again we have a
ring of n vertices in which each is connected to its c nearest neighbors, where c is even.
And again a shortcut is added to the network with probability p for each edge around
the ring, but now instead of connecting random vertex pairs, each shortcut connects a
random vertex to the same single hub vertex in the center of the network:

[image: image of corresponding graph]

This model could be, for example, a model of a (one-dimensional) world connected
together by a bus or train (the central vertex) whose stops are represented by the shortcuts.
Show that the mean distance between two vertices in this network in the limit of
large n is $$ l = \frac{2(c{^2}p + 1)}{c^2p} $$ (which is a constant, independent of n).

Comment: [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/)'s a tutorial and reference for typesetting math on this site.

Comment: What do you mean by $l\sim2(c^2p+l)/c^2p$? Is there a typo?

Comment: Thanks, I corrected it.